# How to create Mock objects for Android Activities (Junit)

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I am fairly new to unit testing, in android specifically.  I have written an application with numerous activities.  However, some of these activities rely on certain objects for them to populate the activity's views.  I guess my question is: Is there a way I can mock up the objects within the Activity and make the activity use that created mock object from my Junit tests?  Thanks in advance, I cant find the solution for this anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refere to the [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) under Create a Local Unit Test Class heading, you will find the answer to your question. Also refer to the "[Mock Android Dependecies](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies)" sub heading on the same page.

Comment: Link no longer works, which is a good example of why answers that are basically RTM (read the manual) are problematic. Better to pull the relevant parts into the answer (while still providing the link), will help prevent link rot from ruining what I'm sure was a good answer at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at AndroidMock:

http://code.google.com/p/android-mock/wiki/UsingAndroidMock

It is a Mock Objects framework for Android build on top of EasyMock.